# Websocket Autobahn Testsuite Unhandled Error (Windows and Ubuntu)

Tags: python, testing, websocket, autobahn

I've just installed **Autobahn Testsuite 0.5.5** on my Windows 7 and Ubuntu.
Every time I want to run it I got the same error.

My setup:

- Python 2.7.5
- setuptools 1.1.6
- Twisted 13.1.0 for Python 2.7
- AutobahnPython 0.6.3

Any idea what might be a cause?
Regards, Adam

**Ubuntu 12.04**

```
Ok, will run 16 test cases against 1 servers
Cases = ['1.1.1', '1.1.2', '1.1.3', '1.1.4', '1.1.5', '1.1.6', '1.1.7', '1.1.8', '1.2.1', '1.2.2', '1.2.3', '1.2.4', '1.2.5', '1.2.6', '1.2.7', '1.2.8']
Servers = [u'ws://127.0.0.1:8099@MyAwesomeServer']
Running test case ID 1.1.1 for agent MyAwesomeServer from peer 127.0.0.1:8099
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wstest", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('autobahntestsuite==0.5.5', 'console_scripts', 'wstest')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autobahntestsuite-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/autobahntestsuite/wstest.py", line 351, in run
    reactor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 485, in connectionLost
    self._commonConnection.connectionLost(self, reason)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-13.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 299, in connectionLost
    protocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autobahntestsuite-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/autobahntestsuite/fuzzing.py", line 1201, in connectionLost
    FuzzingProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autobahntestsuite-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/autobahntestsuite/fuzzing.py", line 211, in connectionLost
    "isServer": self.isServer,
exceptions.AttributeError: FuzzingClientProtocol instance has no attribute 'isServer'
```

**Windows 7**

```
Servers = [u'ws://echo.websocket.org@AutobahnPython']
Running test case ID 1.1.1 for agent AutobahnPython from peer 174.129.224.73:80
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\autobahntestsuite-0.5.5-py2.7.egg\autobahntestsuite\wstest.py", line 351, in run
    reactor.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1192, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1204, in mainLoop
    self.doIteration(t)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 145, in doSelect
    _logrun(selectable, _drdw, selectable, method, dict)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\log.py", line 88, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\log.py", line 73, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 156, in _doReadOrWriteself._disconnectSelectable(selectable, why, method=="doRead")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 257,in _disconnectSelectable
    selectable.readConnectionLost(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 279, in readConnectionLost
    self.connectionLost(reason)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 485, in connectionLost
    self._commonConnection.connectionLost(self, reason)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 299, in connectionLost
    protocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\autobahntestsuite-0.5.5-py2.7.egg\autobahntestsuite\fuzzing.py", line 1201, in connectionLost
    FuzzingProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\autobahntestsuite-0.5.5-py2.7.egg\autobahntestsuite\fuzzing.py", line 211, in connectionLost
    "isServer": self.isServer,
exceptions.AttributeError: FuzzingClientProtocol instance has no attribute 'isServer'
```

Comment: Which AutobahnPython version are you using? Should be 0.5.14. Since: 0.6 was release a couple of days ago, but we need to publish a new AutobahnTestsuite package as well. But that has not yet happened.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem I was using 0.6.3 AutobahnPython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, 
that was the problem I was using AutobahnPython 0.6.3.

**For others:**
If you want to run Autobahn Testsuite 0.5.5 you need to install AutobahnPython 0.5.14: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahn/0.5.14

Comment: AutobahnTestsuite 0.5.6 now support AutobahnPython 0.6.3.